# In a Jasmine unit test, how do I force a failure callback to trigger that would result from a failed request?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, error-handling, jasmine, throw

Let's say I have this method (bellow is the function extrapolated):

```
function doSomething(onSuccess, onFailure){
  var that = this;
  that.$save(function(result){
    if (onSuccess) {
      onSuccess(result);
    }
  }, onFailure);
}
```

I'm already successfully testing that the onSuccess callback fires when that.$save executes as expected, but I'm having trouble finding any documentation on how to make that.$save fail to trigger the onFailure callback.

My attempt at creating a onFailure test looks like:

```
it ('should trigger the failure callback if necessary', function(){
  var  successCallback= jasmine.createSpy('successCallback');
  var  failureCallback= jasmine.createSpy('failureCallback');

  // Force $save to fail to trigger failure callback
  thing.$save = function(){};
  spyOn(thing, '$save').and.throwError('thing.$save error');

  thing.addNew(successCallback, failureCallback);

  expect(failureCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(callback.successCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It still tries to call the success callback as I can tell per this error:

```
Expected spy failureCallback to have been called.
    at /Users/pathy-path
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://website.com/things/5654d74a9b8d05030083239f
No more request expected
```

And if I setup the httpBackend to expect the POST (which it shouldn't since it should fail? At least that seems logical), the test fails because the wrong callback executes: `Expected spy failureCallback to have been called.`

For reference, my onSuccess test looks like this (somewhat simplified):

```
it ('should trigger the success callback', function(){
  var successCallback = jasmine.createSpy('successCallback');
  path = ENV.apiEndpoint + '/things/' + id;
  // if this is triggered we know it would be saved
  $httpBackend.expect('POST', path).respond(201);

  thing.addNew(successCallback);

  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(successCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have it execute the second (`onFailure`) callback

```
spyOn(that, '$save').and.callFake(function(success, fail) {
    fail();
});
```

Comment: This makes my test pass, but it seems as though it's not so much triggering the failureCallback as replacing the .$save method (which is what I was going for above). I've tried a new method bellow that utilizes .$save but triggers the failure rather than deliberately calling it.

Comment: @hiMyNameIs-Name well what **exactly** are you testing here? From your question it appears you're testing `thing` (which I assumed was a controller) which consumes `that` so you should be mocking the `that` interface

Answer (score 0):

I tried Phil's answer (which makes the test pass) but felt that it may not actually be a true test of how the doSomething function executes. To mimic an API failure I ended up using $httpBackend and forcing a 404 response so that Angular's .$save method still executes:

```
it ('should trigger the failure callback if necessary', function(){
  var  successCallback= jasmine.createSpy('successCallback');
  var  failureCallback= jasmine.createSpy('failureCallback');

  // Force $save to fail to trigger failure callback
  path = ENV.apiEndpoint + '/things/' + thing.id;
  $httpBackend.expect('POST', path).respond(404);

  thing.addNew(successCallback, failureCallback);

  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect(failureCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(successCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```